# Reverse a set of list elements and store it to the list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, reverse

What will be the logic or code of this problem? The `reverse()` function does not take any argument and `list[::-1]` is also the same. How to do it in easy way?

Example, given:

```
list = [1,5,4,3,2,6]
```

Reversing 5...2, the output will be:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: got a lot of downvote ! why ?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, you shadow a built-in [function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Answer (score 3):

You could use list slice assignment, which modifies the list in-place:

```
>>> L = [1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6]
>>> L[1:5] = L[4:0:-1]  
>>> L
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reassign the slice of the list to that same slice in reverse

```
l = [1,5,4,3,2,6]
l[1:5] = l[1:5][::-1]
print(l)
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I find `l[1:5] = reversed(l[1:5])` nicer to read, but in principle the same thing.

Comment: `l[4:0:-1]` would be more efficient than `l[1:5][::-1]`, as it would create a new list just once.

Comment: @eugeney I considered doing it that way, but I thought that having the indices be the same was nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
l = [1,5,4,3,2,6]
index5 = l.index(5)
index2 = l.index(2)
l[index5:index2+1] = l[index2:index5-1:-1]
```

If you want it to be more explicit, you could use `reversed`:

```
l[index5:index2+1] = reversed(l[index5:index2+1])
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, could you explain why?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but probably because it only works for lists with unique elements. Not a general solution like the other proposed answers.

Comment: i'm shocked really :(

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

```
>>> l = [1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6]
>>> temp = l[1:5]
>>> temp.reverse()
>>> l[1:5] = temp
>>> l
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Is not what OP wants.